# URL & Geomap Lat/Lon fields are not showing in Target List during mapping in Feed?

Tags: feeds

I am using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. All the fields from node are showing in target list except URL field Type and Geomap Latitude and Longitude Fields. I can't figure out how to map values from CSV to them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to import the data for lat/lon values from CSV file to geoField field lat/lon.

I required to use a patch in "geofield.feeds.inc" file in GeoField module which solves this issue.

You can get this patch from under mentioned URL:

[GeoFiled Feed Patch File](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/geofield-feeds-simple-import-2534822-4.patch)

Hope this patch will help more developers as it does for me too.